# I am having problems storing my answers generated in a loop to different arrays

Tags: python

I'm trying achieve different `v` values for each `Ns` value. I having difficulty with `p`.

`p` saves the previous `Ns` value in each loop. I will like my `v` to be strictly only values from one Ns only. I have tried adding break to my code but I still get similar results.

```py
p = []
LB = 1000

Ns = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
for i in range(len(Ns)):
  if Ns[i] > 3:
     m =(LB / (((2 * 0.8) + (Ns[i] - 2)))) * 0.8
     s = m / 0.8
     n = m + (m / 0.8)
     q = m
     w = n

     while n + s < LB:
           n = n + s
           p += [n]
           v = [q,w,p]

     print(v)
```

I want the output when: 
`Ns[i] = 4 v= [222.22,500,777.77]`
`Ns[i]= 5 v= [173.913,391.30,608.69,826.697].`

Hi my code keeps adding more values to the `p array` with every `Ns[i]` value. So when I do the code as:

`Ns[i] >3, at Ns[i] = 5 i get v = [173.913, 391.30, 777.77,608, 826]` and this is because the `p` has been added to the `p from Ns[i] = 4`. I will like to get a result of `v = [173.913, 391.30, 608, 826]` instead.

Comment: what is LB here ? Also post the expected output.

Comment: LB = 1000. I just edited the question

Comment: Expected output ?

Comment: hi I just edited it and added expected output. Thanks

Comment: Can you please check you indentation in the code. Its hard go understand. In your `while` loop you will never go beyond `break` starting from 1st iteration it seems.

Comment: sorry the break was a mistake. I have edited the code now. if you start from Ns[i] > 3 then it should work

Comment: Yes now the code looks fine. Quick question ->  What is the error you are getting in current code ?

Comment: Hi my code keeps adding more values to the p array with every Ns[i] value. so when i do the code as Ns[i] >3, at Ns[i] = 5 i get v = [173.913, 391.30, 777.77,608, 826] and this is because the p has been added to the p from Ns[i] = 4. i will like to get a result of v = [173.913, 391.30, 608, 826] instead.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once :

```
LB = 1000

Ns = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
for i in range(len(Ns)):
  p = []
  if Ns[i] > 3:
     m =(LB/(((2*0.8)+(Ns[i]-2))))*0.8


     s = m/0.8
     n = m+ (m/0.8)
     q = m
     w =n


     while n + s < LB:

           n = n + s
           p += [n]
     v = [q,w,n]

     print(v) 


Output for Ns[5] is --> [173.91304347826087, 391.304347826087, [608.6956521739131, 826.0869565217392]]
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but i will like to see all the values of p for each Ns[i] value.

Comment: Hey @AminaAliyu, I think I got the output now. Please check.

Comment: Tell me if this works and then I can explain what was the problem.

Comment: hi i ran your code. for Ns[5] I got [173.91304347826087, 391.304347826087, 826.0869565217392]. i cant seem to get a similar answer as you. could you please check the code again.

Comment: I changed it 5 mins after updating. I have pulled out `v=[q,w,n]` out of `while loop`. Please run again. Working fine for me and also shared the output.

Comment: By writing 'n' it inserts a list in 'v'. That will be with brackets. We can remove that as well. Please upvote the answer if it helped. :)